# Should we create vector with fixed size and then push_back if need more or not initialize

Tags: c++, vector

-As we known, push_back will sometime need cost than O(1). So should we create vector like:

```
std::vector<T> v(n); // With n is number we guess the instances T will be used.
```

- Then if we need more we will use push_back when `v.size() == n`
- I think it's performance better than we just use push_back when we need.
  Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code which you posted will default-construct `n` instances of `T`, not just allocate memory for them. Depending on what `T` is, this might be a lot of unnecessary overhead. If you want to just allocate the memory so that the vector doesn't need to be resized as much, you should use [`reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve):

```
std::vector<T> v;
v.reserve(n);
```

Comment: was about to say that

Comment: Well, my bad, I never read about it, I'm was just move from C to C++.  Thank U.